# Line chart with line-grouping based on close values

Tags: d3.js, charts, bigdata, visualization, data-visualization

I have the following issue:

1. I have a chart that shows the ingestion volume overtime by customer ID.
2. Since I have many customers, the chart is impossible to draw, as no chart drawer can produce 100K lines.
3. Yet, most of the customers send more or less the same amount of data, so if we "zoom-out", most of the lines would look like a single fat line.

I would like to be able to define an upper/lower "radius" and have all lines which *would have been* rendered within the radius limits - **as a single line**.

That way, I could present 100K lines using 50-100 lines at most.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is the role of a "data preparation". Instead of providing the 100K lines for drawing, first merge these lines and weight them with this group count. Then when drawing lines, adjust the stroke width of each line based on this "group count".

Comment: I agree, BUT! :), I would like the drawer to allow me to click on one line (potentially hides 100s of customer IDs) and zoom in to to the right Y-axis values and show me many lines (each potentially hiding 10s of customer IDs).

Besides, are you familiar with the logic to actually compute these lines? regardless if it's done on the UI or query engine?

Comment: 1) Concerning the zoom when clicking a line (which can be a merge of lines), I suggest retrieving the associated new y range, which allows you to filter only lines having points within this range, and thus applying the same logic as above to re-draw the graph (grouping similar lines) but on this subset of lines. 2) Lines could be grouped by their set of points: two lines sharing the same set of points could be drawn as a single line with a stroke weight of 2. If it's not enough, maybe you could merge 2 lines if they share the same points given a decimal precision, or 95% of the same points.